# How to use sfRequest instance in a static method?

Tags: php, symfony1, static-methods

I am using symfony 1.0.6 and in action file we can set error using,

```
$this->getRequest()->setError("email", "The email address does not look valid.  Please re-check  the address.");
```

But when used at /lib/model/User.php, with a static function

```
 public static function createNewUser() { 
 if(preg_match("/\bUsername\b/i", $err)) {
                        $sf_request->setError('rusername', "Username already taken. Please choose a different one");    
                    }
                    if(preg_match("/\bemail\b/i", $err)) {
                       $sf_request->setError('Email', "This email address is already registered. Please use another");
                    }

 }
```

It is resulting in an error: "Undefined variable: sfRequest".

How to set error in static method using sfrequest instance ?
Can sfRequest instance be created whilst it is abstract class...?

Comment: or please let me know how t use sfrequest in static methods...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.06 is very old, and no longer officially supported. I would recommend that you consider upgrading to [1.4.x](http://www.symfony-project.org/doc/1_4/), or if you aren't too deep into the project, look into [symfony2](http://symfony.com/). Not sure about 1.06 but in 1.4.x you can do this:

```
sfContext::getInstance()->getRequest();
```